# How to choose a design pattern when your customer' requirements are still a bit hazy

Tags: design-patterns, requirements

I have a flat file containing person "Records" which I get from a service provider. Each Record is in fact a list of Records. 
Each line in the file represents a Record with a given Type. 
A person Record always contains the types '001' and '099', representing a start- and an end Record fora person. Other records are added to a person entry based on an 'incident'. Hence a Record is built based on the given incident.

Example.

```
000 # Start of doc.
001 # Person begin.
...
n Records (n > 001 && n < 099)
...
099 # Person end.
001 # Person begin.
...
n Records (n > 001 && n < 099)
...
099 # Person end.
001 # Person begin.
...
n Records (n > 001 && n < 099)
...
099 # Person end.
999 # End of doc.
```

Apart from the Record Type on each line there are other data contained within fixed positions.

Example of actual start Record

```
0010308952872          01000000000000 K1995-03-01
```

My approach, so far, is to define an .XSD per type of record and use schema binding classes. My problem is that there are still no requirements in regards to what types of records are relevant based on the type of incident. I would just grab a phone and call the person responsible, but working for the public sector makes planning a b****.

Does anyone have any suggestions to which software pattern could adhere most to this type of problem statement? Any sharing of experience would be much appreciated :}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have different types of records and the list of records might grow/change over time.  My first thought would be to code to an interface - abstract the details away so that most of your application isn't affected by changes to the underlying data structures.

I would try to accomplish this by using something like the Strategy pattern combined with the Factory pattern.  Maybe create a ReadStrategyFactory that can return different ReadStrategy implementations based on the record type.

Here's a [link](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-strategy-and-factory-patterns) to an article that I wrote on the subject of the Strategy and Factory patterns - it might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If it is simply a matter of abstracting the **Record** object state. Then create an abstract composite type to represent any record type. This can also be used as the common Interface type that you would use in the Composite Design Pattern. Which allows you to iterate over nearly any type of Data Structure and deals with differing types as a common composite. Search for GOF or other on Composite Design Pattern. If I understand you correctly. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite
Here is one source. Sorry for the raw link. I'm on iPhone.

P.S. I guess I should clarify, that this assumes you are populating some Data Structure when the flat file is read.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to try strategy pattern with Factory. This [github link](https://github.com/santhoser/FileReader) is of a simple example created myself.

From the project :-

The File Reader solution is capable of reading different types for file structures. Read the FileReader_Task.docx inside the BookListApp project to know of the problem (user story) of this solution.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's great to practice and think about design patterns and I certainly encourage you to learn them. I wouldn't recommend approaching problems by thinking of which design pattern can solve them from the get go.

Keep them in the back of your mind but instead try and focus on the actual problem you're trying to solve and apply patterns when you find code smells and there is a need for them. Otherwise you may end up over-engineering or over complicating something. [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) [Refactoring Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213351) may be worth a read.

As for your question the composite or strategy patterns could be appropriate, or maybe a combination of different patterns, but as said above I would suggest solving the problem and then if you discover code smells refactoring to use the appropriate pattern.

Both of these sites have great examples and are a good reference: [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/composite_pattern.htm) and [sourcemaking](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy)